# How to create a For-Loop to edit all text files located in a given folder?

Tags: r, for-loop, text

I need to add additional line gaps between paragraphs in about 5,000 text files. With help from someone here (thanks @IRTFM), I can now pull up a txt file and add the spaces I need to between paragraphs with the code here:

```
txt <- readLines("~/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1/WP_1979.9.16.txt")
spread <- ifelse( nchar(txt) < 50, 
                  paste0(txt, "\n") , # these lines are left alone
                  paste0( txt, "\n\n\n\n") ) # longer lines are padded
cat(spread, file="~/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1/spread.txt" )
```

This code works perfectly on an individual file, but I would now like to scale it up with a for loop (or something else) so that the code runs through all the files in a given folder. I've looked at several questions on this site already and some give me the general idea, but they still aren't working. This is the code I am using:

```
#list of file names needed to conduct for loop
     filenames = list.files(path="~/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1/", pattern="*.txt")

setwd("~/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1")



#FOR LOOP
     for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
       #code to loop 
           txt <- readLines(con = (paste0("~/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1/", i)))      
           spread <- ifelse( nchar(txt) < 50, 
                  paste0(txt, "\n") , # these lines are left alone
                  paste0( txt, "\n\n\n\n") ) # longer lines are padded
           cat(spread, file=paste0("~/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1/","c_", i))
  }
```

But I keep getting connection error saying it cannot open the connection or that there is "No such file or directory". I did notice that in the warning that it also seems to indicate that the character it is adding to the end is the number 1. The problem seems to be located around the `readLines` command.

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/Users/lessig7/Box/Atlas.ti_originals/WP/WP_decade1/1': No such file or directory
```

But I have checked multiple times the values of the filenames list, and they aren't appearing as numbers (see below).

```
> filenames
 [1] "spread.txt"         "WP_1977.6.29.txt"   "WP_1979.9.16.txt"   "WP_1980.9.7.txt"    "WP_1981.7.24.txt"   "WP_1982.1.12.txt"  
 [7] "WP_1982.1.7.txt"    "WP_1982.2.4.txt"    "WP_1982.8.6.txt"    "WP_1983.11.8.txt"   "WP_1983.3.6.txt"    "WP_1983.6.30.txt"  
[13] "WP_1983.7.12.txt"   "WP_1984.1.13.txt"   "WP_1984.1.28.txt"   "WP_1984.3.11.txt"   "WP_1984.3.13_2.txt" "WP_1984.3.13.txt"  
[19] "WP_1984.3.20.txt"   "WP_1984.3.25.txt"   "WP_1984.3.7.txt"    "WP_1984.8.29.txt"   "WP_1984.9.11.txt"   "WP_1984.9.15.txt"  
[25] "WP_1984.9.21.txt"   "WP_1984.9.4.txt"    "WP_1985.1.19.txt"   "WP_1985.11.2.txt"   "WP_1985.11.28.txt"  "WP_1985.6.16.txt"  
[31] "WP_1985.6.6.txt"    "WP_1985.7.16.txt"   "WP_1985.7.2.txt"    "WP_1985.8.12.txt"   "WP_1985.8.16.txt"   "WP_1985.8.2.txt"   
[37] "WP_1986.10.11.txt"  "WP_1986.11.1.txt"   "WP_1986.11.8.txt"   "WP_1986.12.19.txt"  "WP_1986.12.21.txt"  "WP_1986.12.27.txt" 
[43] "WP_1986.8.18.txt"   "WP_1986.8.25.txt"   "WP_1987.12.12.txt"  "WP_1987.12.25.txt"  "WP_1987.3.8.txt"    "WP_1987.4.2.txt"   
[49] "WP_1988.1.17.txt"   "WP_1988.1.5.txt"    "WP_1988.1.7.txt"    "WP_1988.10.22.txt"  "WP_1988.10.29.txt"  "WP_1988.10.8.txt"  
[55] "WP_1988.10.9.txt"   "WP_1988.11.27.txt"  "WP_1988.12.11.txt"  "WP_1988.12.6.txt"   "WP_1988.3.22.txt"   "WP_1988.4.21.txt"  
[61] "WP_1988.4.8.txt"    "WP_1988.7.20.txt"   "WP_1988.8.29.txt"   "WP_1988.8.30.txt"   "WP_1988.9.17.txt"   "WP_1988.9.28.txt"  
[67] "WP_1988.9.6.txt"    "WP_1989.10.12.txt"  "WP_1989.10.21.txt"  "WP_1989.10.27.txt"  "WP_1989.12.1.txt"   "WP_1989.12.5.txt"  
[73] "WP_1989.2.13.txt"   "WP_1989.2.9.txt"    "WP_1989.3.17.txt"   "WP_1989.3.3_2.txt"  "WP_1989.3.3.txt"    "WP_1989.5.11.txt"  
[79] "WP_1989.5.31.txt"   "WP_1989.7.10.txt"   "WP_1989.7.24.txt"   "WP_1989.7.29.txt"   "WP_1989.7.8.txt"    "WP_1989.8.21.txt"  
[85] "WP_1989.9.17.txt"   "WP_1989.9.9.txt"
```

Any advice that might help me create a loop through the code I provide in the first code box would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe in your `readLines` statement with `paste0` you want `filenames[i]` instead of just `i`?

Comment: @Ben suggestion, you might find `list.files full.names=TRUE` is useful, setwd with trailing `/`, what does length(filenames) tell you?

Comment: And `txt[[i]]` wants its `i` too so that file one is processed to txt one and so on. Define txt, probably as an empty list `txt <- list()`, outside the loop.